# Vertically align two blocks on the right side of page

Tags: html, css

I have two blocks: a need help message bubble and a chatbox block that always need to stay on the right side of the page right at the middle of it; and no matter the viewport size, they should always be vertically aligned with the same space between them.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="tooltiptext">
    <span>Need help</span>
</div>
<div id="sticky">
    <img src="images/chatbox-icon.png" width="29" alt="">
    <span>Chat</span>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#sticky{
    background: #FFAE02;
    width: 119px;
    height: 47px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 87%;
    right: 2%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0 10px;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#sticky span{
    color: black;
    font-family:Lato, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;  font-size: 18px;
}
#tooltiptext {
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 3px 0;
    top: 80%;
    right: 2.5%;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
#tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFF transparent transparent transparent;
}
#tooltiptext span{
    color: black;
    font-family:Lato, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;

}
```

I have three issues with this code:

- When the viewport changes, the blocks shift down the page on the right and,
- The spacing between the blocks changes
- The page gets expanded , adds white space on the right side

I cannot figure out where the problem is. any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is your top and bottom attributes. Easy fix by changing their values. Works just fine for all screens, stretch a bit when the height is very low, but I dont think is never gonna happen on any device

```css
#sticky{
    background: #FFAE02;
    width: 119px;
    height: 47px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0 10px;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#sticky span{
    color: black;
    font-family:Lato, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;  font-size: 18px;
}
#tooltiptext {
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding: 3px 0;
    top: 43%;
    right: 2.5%;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
#tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFF transparent transparent transparent;
}
#tooltiptext span{
    color: black;
    font-family:Lato, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;

}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="tooltiptext">
            <span>Need help</span>
        </div>
        <div id="sticky">
            <img src="images/chatbox-icon.png" width="29" alt="">
            <span>Chat</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Trillyy for your contribution. It does work. The only problem is that the blocks should initially be positioned in the middle of the page no matter the viewport. How can it be achieved?